# this program is supposed to show the function of constructive and destructive function in class

Tags: c++

> Unfortunately i got this error:no instance of overloaded function `strcpy_s` matches the argument list.I don't know what  dose it mean??
>   would you mind helping me.

```
//......................................................
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class one
{
    char *s;
public:
    one()
    {
        cout << "constructive\n";
    }
    void f(char *str)
    {
        s = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy_s(s, str);
    }
    void f1()
    {
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
    ~one()
    {
        cout << "destructive";
    }
};
one f2()
{
    char s[80];
    one x;
    cout << "enter a string: \n";
    gets_s(s);
    x.f(s);
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    one a;
    a = f2();
    a.f1();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
//................................................
```

Comment: Would you mind properly formatting your question and code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the compiler can't find the function, and that's because you didn't `#include <cstring>`.

Comment: @Kas​​​​​​​​​​​ra: Then you do not have a C11-compliant compiler. Either way you need to _read the documentation_ to find out that the requirements are for functions that you want to use.

Comment: i use visual studio 2015.actually my english is not very good.but thank a lot for your response.that was really kind of you

Comment: @Kasra: Well you've also got the wrong number of arguments, so that doesn't help. That function takes three, not two. Which standard library reference are you using? Here's some documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx